# Design: "Add Comment" and "start a bounty" look out of place

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Under each question there are two links that I think need some TLC.

> [image]

These two poor links are all alone in a sea of whitespace. They are clearly an odd couple: They don't line up and they have inconsistent capitalisation,

But fate has forced them together, and revealed that they have something in common. They both don't look like links and they don't look like buttons.

Is there a way to rescue these poor orphans?

Comment: there was originally a nice design plan. i'lll adjust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be fixed. I don't have enough rep to see "add bounty" here to check :/